# How to reorder a legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a two column data frame with a categorical column of labels and a quantitative column of percent data, I can reliably produce a bar chart in ggplot that sorts the bars by value rather than by alphabetical order using the following:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(Label, Percent), y=Percent, fill=Label)) + geom_bar()
```

This tells reorder to sorts the bar chart by the percent value rather than the text, making it easier to see the changes.

I cannot, however, get the legend to match: instead it persists in being sorted by the original alphabetical values. This results in a legend which doesn't match the chart, which is confusing.

I've looked on StackOverflow and elsewhere, and haven't found a fix that will work. Any advice?

Edit: per requests, this is essentially the data:

```
Labels <- c("G", "G", "A", "C", "M", "B", "M", "G", "A","M")
Percent <- c("-0.241","-0.046", "-0.037", "-0.024", "-0.003","0.007","0.01","0.059","0.121", "0.152")
```

Comment: Can you provide a representative example of your `df` so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Have you tried something like `+ scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("Top","Middle","Bottom"))`?

Comment: Data provided. As for scale_fill_discrete, that did not solve the problem. Any other questions, just let me know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find the easiest way is to just reorder your data *before* plotting. By specifying the `reorder(()` inside `aes()`, you essentially making a ordered copy of it for the plotting parts, but it's tricky internally for `ggplot` to pass that around, e.g. to the legend making functions.

This should work just fine:

```
df$Label  <- with(df, reorder(Label, Percent))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Label, y=Percent, fill=Label)) + geom_bar()
```

I do assume your `Percent` column is numeric, not factor or character. This isn't clear from your question. In the future, if you post `dput(df)` the classes will be unambiguous, as well as allowing people to copy/paste your data into R.

Comment: This is easier because it solves the color problem at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

With the data you provided, the following works for me basically applying the suggestion from Frank:

```
Labels <- c("G", "G", "A", "C", "M", "B", "M", "G", "A","M")
Percent <- c("-0.241","-0.046", "-0.037", "-0.024", "-0.003","0.007","0.01","0.059","0.121", "0.152")
df <- data.frame(Labels, Percent)
df$Percent <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Percent))
legend_ord <- levels(with(df, reorder(Labels, Percent)))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(Labels, Percent), y = Percent, fill=Labels)) 
p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p + scale_fill_discrete(breaks=legend_ord)
```

[image]

Regarding your followup question, if you have specific colors you can assign them within the `scale_fill_manual` call.

```
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(Labels, Percent), y = Percent, fill=Labels)) 
p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity")
p + scale_fill_manual(breaks=legend_ord, 
    values=c("G"="#0000FF", "C"="#003FBF","B"="#007F7F","A"="#00BF3F","M"="#00FF00"))
```

[image]