# How does reorder function work?

Tags: r

Let

```
vetA <- structure(
  c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
  .Label = c("Two", "One", "Three"), 
  class = "factor"
)
vetB <- reorder(vetA, c(9,1,2,3,4,8,7,6,10,5))
plot(vetA)
plot(vetB)
```

The plots show differently.

`plot(VetA)`

[image]

`plot(VetB)`

[image]

However, reading the `?reorder` manual, I didn't understand how the function works and how to manipulated it, so I could display the bars in this order `One Two Three`. Also, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872905/how-to-reorder-a-legend-in-ggplot2) post in which uses reorder. But, 
it got me more confused because he used as a second argument a vector not with index, but with *percent*.

So, could you please have some mercy & give me a hand?

Comment: `reorder()` puts the bars in the order of increasing mean (because that's the default function) of the vector `c(9,1,2,3,4,8,7,6,10,5)`.

Comment: I usually use `factor` rather than `reorder`, which is maybe a little more intuative for simply defining the order you want.  `vetB <- factor(VetA, levels = c("One","Two","Three"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `factor` and specify in which order the levels are. You can also mark the factor as an *ordered* factor.

```
vetC <- factor(vetA, levels = c("One", "Two","Three"))
plot(vetC)
```