# How to specifically change the order of legend in barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, bar-chart, legend

[image]

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = plotDf,
           aes(x = reorder(plotDf$sample_id), y = counts, fill = condition), 
           stat = 'identity') + 
labs(x = 'Sample') + 
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+ 
scale_fill_manual (values = cbPalette)
```

Hello everyone,

The above is my code and barplot.  I would like to change the order of sample and legend to 'wt''wt_dia''wt_afn', 'wt_2mut', 'wt_1mut' , which is same as in my `dataframe(plotDf)`. but here apparently, the order is shown in an alphabetical manner. Thanks very much!

Comment: Make your variable into a factor with the levels in the correct order. Do this outside of the ggplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reorder a legend in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872905/how-to-reorder-a-legend-in-ggplot2)

Comment: in addition, please have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example