# Why does ggplot2 automatically order the legend alphabetically? And is there a way to change this default behavior?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I understand that you can simply reorder your levels to achieve the order you want in a ggplot. However, when you are working with 20+ levels this becomes cumbersome. I also understand that I can then write a sorting script to order them in a way to match the ggplot.

My question is: why does ggplot2 do this behavior? You hardly ever want a plot to have an alphabetical legend. Instead you want the legend to match the categories in the plot as they appear.

My second question is: is there a way to change ggplot2's behavior to order the levels as they appear rather than alphabetically?

Comment: Alphabetical is the default for strings. If you change your strings to factors ggplot will order them according to the factor ordering.

Comment: And there is `forcats::fct_inorder` which lets you convert to a factor with the order of the levels set according to the order in the data.

Comment: No-one but Hadley knows for sure why ggplot has the design it has. But alphabetical ordering is everywhere in R, e.g. when simply running `factor(char)` you will also get alphabetical ordering. AFAIK there is no way to change this, and for what it's worth, I almost never need the legend to be in the order of appearance in the data either.

Comment: Reproducible example is missing, so it is hard to provide help. As Simon Woodward said, sorting alphabetically is the default behavior of `ggplot2`. Changing the string variable you are interested in into a factor with the order of the levels you need will produce the correct ordering. It will require some extra work, but that's how it is.

Comment: If I want the items to appear in the order they appear in the data, I use `aes(fill = factor(var, unique(var)))` instead of `aes(fill = var)`. It's not _that_ cumbersome.

Comment: Sorry to say this. If you have 10+ levels and to show them in one plot is not a good idea!  Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872905/how-to-reorder-a-legend-in-ggplot2 this post may helps

Comment: Hi all, appreciate all the helpful comments. I still personally think having an option to order a legend based on level/factor appearance in the plot could be helpful but I see how reordering in the data is more effecient. @AMS ty the link you sent has the answer.